# Nested Partial form Edit Link_to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to, form-for

I've been staring at this for hours and I know it only a tiny error somewhere but I don't know enough to see it yet.

I used this website to create the first part of the blog and for the last 3 hours I've been trying to add an edit link so users can edit the comments and update.

http://www.reinteractive.net/posts/32

Let the coding begin:

Books Model

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
  validates_presence_of :title
  has_many :snippets
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :snippets
end
```

Snippet (Comment) Model

```
 class Snippet < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :book
   belongs_to :user
   attr_accessible :body, :user_id
 end
```

Snippet Controller

```
class SnippetsController < ApplicationController   
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:create]

  def create
    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
    @snippet = @book.snippets.create!(params[:snippet])
    redirect_to @book
  end      

  def edit
    @snippet = Snippet.find(params[:book_id])
  end        

  def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @snippet = @book.comments.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC')
  end    
end
```

Snippet _form.html.erb

```
<% form_for([@book, @snippet], :url => edit_book_snippet_path(@book)) %>
  <%= form.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
```

This is why I cannot understand when I look at the rake routes I get this:

> edit_book_snippet GET    /books/:book_id/snippets/:id/edit(.:format)
>   snippets#edit

My route is this

```
> http://localhost:3000/books/3/snippets/12/edit
```

but my error is still this:

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"snippets",
>   :book_id=>nil}

Started learning rails from treehouse but got to intermediate and preferred to learn the harder (but more fun) way.

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your stack trace errors, you could see that `book_id` is nil ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to specify the book in the `edit` action of your controller, and since you need it in several actions of your controller, you could create a `before_filter` callback to make your code more DRY.

For example:

```
class SnippetsController < ApplicationController   
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:create]
  before_filter :find_book

  def create
    @snippet = @book.snippets.create!(params[:snippet])
    redirect_to @book
  end      

  def edit
    @snippet = Snippet.find(params[:id])
  end        

  private

  def find_book
    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  end
end
```

I removed the `show` action of the controller because it should be used to display one snippet, not all the snippets of a book. To do so, you can use the `index` action of the `SnippetsController`, or better, the `show` action of the `BooksController`.

One last thing, the url you use in the form declaration is wrong because you need to specify both the book and the snippet:

```
<%= form_for([@book, @snippet], :url => edit_book_snippet_path(@book, @snippet)) do |f| %>
```

To get the basis of a blog creation with Rails, I suggest you to read the classic [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

Comment: Thanks, so far this seemed to help. I do want to display all snippets and all books later on. However I put the form url in the partial as this <% form_for([@book, @snippet], :url => edit_book_snippet_path(@book, @snippet)) %> but now I'm getting an argument error:   **ArgumentError in Snippets#edit

Showing C:/Users/Shaun/Dropbox/treebook/app/views/snippets/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

Missing block**

Comment: I just edited my answer, see also the `=` at the beginning of the line

Comment: Thanks man. I did that and had a look through that link you sent me and it is very helpful. The site I looked at didn't give you enough detail. I'll now try the delete method myself and most likely end up staring at another syntax error for 4 hours

Comment: Quick one, I'm now getting another error when I try to #show a book on the index, No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"snippets", :book_id=>#<Book id: 1, title: "A man and his dog", created_at: "2013-09-24 09:33:57", updated_at: "2013-09-24 09:33:57">, :id=>nil}

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not working because in your `edit` action you have the following

```
@snippet = Snippet.find(params[:book_id])
```

but in your `_form` partial you call `@book`:

```
<% form_for([@book, @snippet], :url => edit_book_snippet_path(@book)) %>
```

in any case the `edit_book_snippet_path(@book)` is wrong as you should provide both required id's, as the route asks for

```
books/**:book_id/snippets/**:id/edit
```

It would be better written like this (although you could also create a `before_filter` like you have for authenticate user for `@book` and/or `@snippet` as you'll probably use them a lot in this controller)

`snippet_controller.rb`

```
def edit
  @book = Book.find(params[:id]) 
  @snippet = Book.snippets.find(params[:book_id])
end
```

`_form.html.erb`

```
<% form_for([@book, @snippet], :url => edit_book_snippet_path(book_id: @book.id, id: @snippet.id)) %>
```

Comment: Thanks Dax, you helped me as well.